# How to get an array with a timeseries slice in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script

I have the following code in `Pinescript` where I am basically trying to slice a timeseries into an array to be used within `NextFunction`.

When using an array instantiated directly with `array.from`, `NextFunction` works correctly. But when instantiated by `LoadArray`, it does not work. Why would be it so? How to turn `LoadArray` into a function compatible with `NextFunction`?

**Ps.:** `NextFunction` uses matrices to perform its computations.

```
LoadArray(series, length) =>
    res = array.new_float(length)
    for i = length - 1 to 0
        array.set(res, i, series[i])
    res := res

NextFunction(y) =>
    ...
    ...

y = LoadArray(close, 5)
y2 = array.from(1212.3, 1211.6, 1212.7, 1214.8, 1216.1)

res1 = NextFunction(y2) // works alright
res2 = NextFunction(y) // does not work
```

I expected that the resulting arrays `y` and `y2` would be equal and behave in the very same way within `NextFunction`. But they, for any reason, do not.

I tried to use [History Referencing](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html?highlight=array#history-referencing) without success.

---

**UPDATE 27 - 12 - 2022**

Still the functionality I am willing to perform is not working. So I decided to disclose the whole script in the attempt of better understanding why `LoadArrayA` and `LoadArrayC` fail to produce a valid `coef` array.

```
var global_print_counter = array.new_int()
array.push(global_print_counter, 0)

print(txt = "") => 
    if txt != "" and barstate.islast
        int print_counter = array.get(global_print_counter, 0)
        printLabel = label.new(x=bar_index, y=high - print_counter*7500, textcolor=color.white, color=color.black, text=txt)
        array.set(global_print_counter, 0, print_counter + 1)

//@version=5
indicator(title="LoadArray Test", shorttitle="LT", format=format.volume)

PowerSummation(vector0, power0, vector1, power1) =>
    var accumulator = 0.0
    for i = 0 to array.size(vector0) - 1
        accumulator += math.pow(array.get(vector0, i), power0)*math.pow(array.get(vector1, i), power1)
    accumulator := accumulator

GetCoefficients(x, y) =>
    int n = array.size(x)
    var coefficients = array.from(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    var A = matrix.new<float>(3, 3, 0)
    var idv = array.new_float(array.size(x), 1)

    float ex1 = PowerSummation(x, 1, idv, 0)
    float ex2 = PowerSummation(x, 2, idv, 0)
    float ex3 = PowerSummation(x, 3, idv, 0)
    float ex4 = PowerSummation(x, 4, idv, 0)
    var ex = array.from(ex1, ex2, ex3, ex4)

    matrix.set(A, 0, 0, n)
    matrix.set(A, 0, 1, ex1)
    matrix.set(A, 0, 2, ex2)
    matrix.set(A, 1, 0, ex1)
    matrix.set(A, 1, 1, ex2)
    matrix.set(A, 1, 2, ex3)
    matrix.set(A, 2, 0, ex2)
    matrix.set(A, 2, 1, ex3)
    matrix.set(A, 2, 2, ex4)

    var B = matrix.new<float>(3, 1, 0)

    float b3 = PowerSummation(x, 2, y, 1)
    float b2 = PowerSummation(x, 1, y, 1)
    float b1 = PowerSummation(idv, 0, y, 1)    

    matrix.set(B, 0, 0, b1)
    matrix.set(B, 1, 0, b2)
    matrix.set(B, 2, 0, b3)
    
    var invA = matrix.inv(A)
    var X = matrix.mult(invA, B)
    coefficients := array.from(matrix.get(X, 0, 0), matrix.get(X, 1, 0), matrix.get(X, 2, 0))

LoadArrayA(series, length) =>
    res = array.new_float(length)
    for i = length - 1 to 0
        array.set(res, i, series[i])
    res := res

LoadArrayB(series, length) =>
    res = array.from(1219.23, 1219.54, 1220.57, 1221.2, 1221.01)
    res := res

LoadArrayC(series, length) => 
    res = array.new_float() 
    for i = length - 1 to 0 
        array.unshift(res, series[i]) 
    res := res

Linspace(length) =>
    res = array.new_float(length)
    for i = 0 to array.size(res) - 1
        array.set(res, i, i)
    res := res
    
x = Linspace(5)
y = LoadArrayB(close, 5) // works
// y = LoadArrayA(close, 5) // does not produce valid coef
// y = LoadArrayC(close, 5) // does not produce valid coef

coef = GetCoefficients(x, y)
print(str.tostring(coef))
```

---

**UPDATE 29 - 12 - 2022**

Adding `nz` to `LoadArrayA` and `LoadArrayC` implementations prevents nan readings but still the computed `coef` array turns out to be incorrect.

```
LoadArrayA(series, length) =>
    res = array.new_float(length)
    for i = length - 1 to 0
        array.set(res, i, nz(series[i]))
    res := res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to protect against `na` values, which are creeping into the calculations on early bars before the series has enough history to reference. You can wait until the number of bars processed on the chart is greater than your length, or you can use `nz()` to replace `na` values. Can try a modified array function that incorporates `nz()` like the following, so that the array is populated with values other than `na` on early history:

```
LoadArrayC(series, length) =>
    res = array.new_float(length)
    for i = length - 1 to 0
        array.set(res, i, nz(series[i]))
    res
```

In the `PowerSummation()` function, `accumulator` is declared with `var`. This cause values to cumulate through out history continuing to sum on each bar adding to the same value. By removing it, we will only sum the array elements on each bar individually

```
PowerSummation(vector0, power0, vector1, power1) =>
    float accumulator = 0.0
    for i = 0 to array.size(vector0) - 1
        accumulator += math.pow(array.get(vector0, i), power0)*math.pow(array.get(vector1, i), power1)
    accumulator
```

Finally, within the `GetCoefficients()` function, `invA` and `X` are declared with `var`. This is particularly important to remove. Declaring this with `var` causes them to calculate on the first bar in history and hold that value for the entire runtime while the other variables remain dynamic.

Cheers and good luck with your coding.

Comment: This works around the immediate problem but evidences a bug in PineScript. Once there is enough data in close series, computations should not return a NaN array.

Comment: Additionally analysing deeper this solution I found out that if you insert the very same values taken from close time series within LoadArrayA and insert them in LoadArrayB, the resulting coef array turns out to be different.

Comment: Your first comment is incorrect. Adding values to na values will always return na. Because they are introduced on early bars, the result is na to which they will stay. Here is a simple script to simulate the issue where count is rendered na on the first bar, and thus the sum of closes will continue to return na. This is expected behaviour

Comment: `//@version=5 indicator("Test")
var float count = 0
var float count2 = 0 
count += close[1]
count2 += nz(close[1]) 
plot(count) plot(count2)`

Comment: Thank you for your contribution @Bjorgum. I just updated the question contemplating this strategy.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `var` declaration of the accumulator variable? By using var you would get a sum of all array elements on every bar, rather than just the current array elements.

Comment: Removing `var` did not alter the computation results of `PowerSummation`.

Comment: Well I'll leave the math to you. At least we proved there is #notabug

Comment: What is the functional outcome you are trying to achieve anyway? What is the purpose and expected result. All this seems like a lot of hooplah for some coefficient

Comment: What is being performed is a Quadratic regression. It was not proven yet there is not a bug in PineScript language though. The quadratic regression should give the exact correct coefficients. Why would an array work from `LoadArrayB` and why would another with the very same values not from `LoadArrayA`...?

Comment: Remove `var` on `accumulator` declaration, remove `var` on `X` and `invA`. I think you should go back to the basics as there are a handful of mistakes like the `na` thing, not understanding the runtime, or using `var` where you shouldn't. You need to update the question to make it clear what you're trying to achieve. The 2 arrays will return different results because one has constant values throughout the runtime and the other does not. The use of `var` means these values are cumulative, or in the case of the variables returning matrix functions declared with `var`, computed on the first bar.

Comment: Doing what you have just commented above fixed it. I suggest you to post as a solution so that I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

The two arrays don't contain the same type of variable.
y2 (array.from) contains float type 
y (LoadArray) contains a serie float type, as [x] return a serie of values (see [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_[]](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%5B%5D))
It seems that your NextFunction does work with float only.

Switching to the following `LoadArray` implementation should fix it.

```
LoadArray(series, length) =>
    res = array.new<float>(length, series)
    res := res
```

Comment: Using array.new<float>(length, series) solves that error but all the loaded array elements are equal when they should actually reflect the chart data.

Comment: for the array.from, what is the order of the numbers as in close[0], close[1] etc?

Comment: @JohnBaron, yes, that is the order. Why do you ask? In fact the order should not matter here...

Answer (score 0):

> Could you change

```
LoadArray(series, length) =>
    res = array.new_float(length)
    for i = length - 1 to 0
        array.set(res, i, series[i])
```

> To:

```
LoadArray(series, length) => 
    res = array.new_float() 
    for i = length - 1 to 0 
        array.unshift(res, series[i])
```

> ?
>
> With the first technique you would fill the array with the same
> copies, setting them will set all, the only result you'd get is from
> the last iteration.
>
> If that doesn't work, we really need more information ☺️

Answer posted by @fikira12 on https://t.me/PineCodersQA

Comment: That did not work either. I posted additional information in the UPDATE 27-12-2022.